# Android WebView error

Tags: android, webview

I'm a beginner in learning Android, please help me with this.
I keep getting this error:

> 02-19 16:55:00.330: E/AndroidRuntime(2335):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.mkyong.android/com.mkyong.android.WebViewActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
    mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
}
```

my xml file:

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: your WebView instance is probably null. Edit your question and Post your `webview.xml` layout file contents there.

Comment: Could you post your xml? the null pointer exception mean you're referring to something that doesn't exist. also, the logcat will post which line caused the error, posting the specific line is also extremely helpful

Comment: @Ali try to clean and rebuild your project. There does not seems any error with your code at this point.

Comment: Is your xml file named webview.xml?

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong in your code..

Comment: actually Eclipse should show an error on this line webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  cause the webView has not been declared (unless this is your class field)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's this line

> webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

You never say what webView is. You declare mywebview, but not webView

Comment: Perhaps you meant: mywebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);